# Cannot clear DNS cache on MacOS Monterey

Tags: networking, macos, dns, cache, macos-monterey

As part of troubleshooting networking issues on my Macbook Pro running MacOS Monterey 12.3.1, I have setup the WLAN network connection to use two different, local DNS servers, which both contained a record to the same domain name, but pointing to a different IP address.

I have now finished the troubleshooting and the computer is now only pointing to the one DNS server pointing to the correct IP address for the domain name in question, however, no matter how many times I try clearing the DNS cache, restarting the web browser and terminal windows and restarting the computer, There is still a record of the pointer to the other (wrong) IP address present in the system, and when querying the DNS record for the domain in question using both dig and nslookup, both IP addresses are returned.

I have tried clearing the DNS cache using the following terminal command:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

multiple times, and also rebooting the computer multiple times, but the erroneous DNS entry still resides alongside the correct one.

Why is my DNS cache not cleared when running the above command?

Comment: `dig` and `nslookup` use their own built-in DNS resolver code, not the system's name resolution subsystem. You probably still have the old DNS address in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you want to see what the system's resolver is returning, use the `dns-sd` command. If you're still having problems, edit your Question to include the output of `scutil --dns`.